# HTML Form class: add_field method parameter structure [updated]

Tags: php, forms, class

I am trying to write my own class for HTML form rendering. I got stuck on `add_field` method. I have read a couple of posts on SO and other sites but cannot figure out how to manage that method. This is where I got so far:

```
class Form {

    private $output = null;

    /**
     *
     * @param array $form Simple array with the following data: ['form name', 'method', 'action', 'html id', 'html class']
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * The order of the parameter parameter must be the said one. Form name, form method and form action are mandatory.
     * Any extra element from the 5 said will be ignored.
     */
    function __construct(array $form) {
        if (empty($form)) throw new Exception("Form data cannot be empty");
        if (count($form) < 3) throw new Exception("Form name, form method and form action are mandatory");
        if (empty($form[0])) throw new Exception("Form name cannot be an empty string");
        if (empty($form[1])) throw new Exception("Form method cannot be an empty string");
        if (empty($form[2])) throw new Exception("Form action cannot be an empty string");
        $this->output = "\n<form name='$form[0]' method='$form[1]' action='$form[2]'";
        if (array_key_exists(3, $form)) $this->output .= " id='$form[3]'";
        if (array_key_exists(4, $form)) $this->output .= " class='$form[4]'";
        $this->output .= ">";
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * $data format is the following depending on the input type:
     *
     * [text/hidden/email/etc, [name, id, class, value]]
     *
     *
     */
    function add_field(array $data) {
        if (empty($data)) throw new Exception("Field data cannot be empty");

    }

    function render() {
        return $this->output . "\n</form>\n";
    }
}
```

I would appreciate on which should be `add_field`s array parameter format approach.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify my request, what I am stuck on is on how should I structure the array parameter on `add_field` method.

Comment: The class should have an array of form fields. `add_field()` will then add an item to that array. The method for rendering the form would then iterate through the array, rendering each one appropriately.

Comment: @Barmar good advice, thank you. However, I was asking on how to structure `add_field` parameter. I will update title and clarify post.

Comment: You're designing this, you choose how to structure it. Probably two arguments: `$type` and `$attributes`. `$type` can be something like `input`, `menu`, `checkbox`, etc. `$attributes` would be an associative array of attributes.

Comment: @Barmar i was thinking that same approach but was unsure because all I saw was pseudocode and minimal examples and I try to write the most closely to the "standard" I can. I guess I should have  a couple of arrays to validate html input's and accepted attributes.

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum, we can't help you brainstorm designs.